# Clip long text inside HTML table cells, show entire content on hover

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a table html table which has a column named "address". The address contains very long strings. What I want is I only want to show first 2 or 3 words of the address and when I hover over it, it should show full address. How can I do this with html table?

Comment: show us code or demo or else how can we help!!

Comment: For your first request, use css `overflow: hidden;` or `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. I'll try your second request (display it on hover)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```css
.cell {
  max-width: 50px; /* tweak me please */
  white-space : nowrap;
  overflow : hidden;
}

.expand-small-on-hover:hover {
  max-width : 200px; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.expand-maximum-on-hover:hover {
  max-width : initial; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        ID
      </th>
      <th>
        Adress
      </th>
      <th>
        Comment
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td class="cell expand-maximum-on-hover">
        A very, very long adress that cannot be showed entirely
      </td>
      <td class="cell expand-small-on-hover">
        A very, very long comment to add more information to the row it belongs to.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You might begin from there, this is an example of how to use `max-width` combined with `overflow : hidden`.

**Pass hover the adress cell to see the result**

Comment: It works, but the cell is expanding too much that I need to drag the cell content with mouse to the right to view the full text

Answer (score 18):

Solution:

- Use `table-layout: fixed` so that your table columns maintain fixed size
- Wrap the content inside div elements and manipulate width and overflow properties

```css
/*
 * fixed table layout
 */
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  font: larger monospace;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
}
/*
 * inline-block elements expand as much as content, even more than 100% of parent
 * relative position makes z-index work
 * explicit width and nowrap makes overflow work
 */
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/*
 * higher z-index brings element to front
 * auto width cancels the overflow
 */
div:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div>John Smith</div></td>
      <td><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div></td>
      <td><div>1-234-567890</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Jane Doe</div></td>
      <td><div>Suspendisse lacinia, nunc sed luctus egestas, dolor enim vehicula augue.</div></td>
      <td><div>1-234-567890</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer is great, but I'm working with table items that are very long strings, and so when you hover over them, the text goes way off screen. Is there a way to have the text stay in it's "column" and grow height-wise as opposed to width-wise? I've tried playing around with this CSS to make it do just that, but CSS isn't exactly my forte.

Comment: I can't test right now, but one trick is to change the `white-space: nowrap` to `white-space: normal` on hover. There should be side effects but hopefully you (or someone else) might work around them.

Comment: I'm not worried about the side effects at all. That was exactly what I needed. Made a JSFiddle to test it out if anyone happens by and is looking for something similar: https://jsfiddle.net/kxso85w2/1/

Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 8):

Using Tootips gives a solution,

```html
<html>
  <table border="1" >
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td><abbr title="Ab df df dfdf df dfdkjf sdfk dfdf">Ab df df</abbr> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td><abbr title="Bb df df dfdf df dfdkjf sdfk dfdf">Bb df df</abbr> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: add css-rule: text-decoration: unset in order to remove the dots

Comment: Thats correct. The dots supposed to be there to show the text is partial and you can hover it to see it. So, no need of the css rule in this case.